# sqlite 3 sum with inner join returns twice the value it should

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

i am running a query that looks like this

```
SELECT SUM(KILLCOUNT),SPECIES.SPECIES 
FROM TRIP_DATA  JOIN SPECIES
ON TRIP_DATA.SPECIES=SPECIES.SPECIESIDNO
where TRIP_DATA.TRIPID=413 
group by TRIP_DATA.SPECIES.
```

for this trip (413) I ma getting the output, 2 hares and 6 rabbits, however I have only entered 1 hare and 3 rabbits in the database. I cannot see why I am returning double the amount I want. Any advice or corrections to my understanding would be greatly received

for completeness I attach the create statements on the two tables I am joining

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                    +TRIP_DATA
                    +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,TRIPID INTEGER NOT NULL,GMTTIMESTAMP INTEGER NOT NULL,LATITUDE REAL NOT NULL," +
                    "LONGITUDE REAL NOT NULL, ALTITUDE REAL,ACCURACY REAL,SPEED REAL,SPECIES INTEGER,KILLCOUNT INTEGER);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+
                    SPECIES+
                    " (SPECIES TEXT NOT NULL,ISHUNTED INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT (1),SPECIESIDNO INTEGER NOT NULL, EXPANSION TEXT);"
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not inserting more entries in the database by mistake(did you test this with a basic query to see how many you have)?

Comment: Show the data in these records.

Comment: What about changing `FROM TRIP_DATA  JOIN SPECIES` to `FROM TRIP_DATA INNER JOIN SPECIES` (mind the `INNER`) keyword.

Comment: I am not inserting duplicate entries and I have run this query on dummy data and added the columns myself and they are double. I have tried the inner join and this is still giving me the wrong result, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time and research this is the answer that I was looking for

```
SELECT DISTINCT SPECIES.SPECIES,S.COUNT
FROM SPECIES 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT SUM(KILLCOUNT) AS COUNT,TRIP_DATA.SPECIES
    FROM TRIP_DATA
    WHERE TRIPID="+tripid+" AND NOT TRIP_DATA.SPECIES =0 
    GROUP BY TRIP_DATA.SPECIES
)S
ON SPECIES.SPECIESIDNO=S.SPECIES
```

As I understand it (please be aware that this is at the limits of my understanding) when you do an inner join the aggregate functions work on the both primary keys of the joined tables.

this means that my original approach was never going to work, however if make a inner statement using the group buy and use the on word to add the data to the already grouped table it works

many thanks for the comments, I hope helps someone else